# Is there an implementation of += and -= operators for R?

Tags: r, operators

I'm looking for an implementation of `+=` and `-=` in `R`. Anyone built that yet?

```
a = 1
a += 2 # 3
a -= 2 # -1
```

Comment: It's not possible in that format. The R parser just won't allow that syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not exist in R default operators however you can manage to do something similar to it using roperators package as follows;

```
install.packages('roperators')
require(roperators)

# Assignment
a <- 1
print(a)
# [1] 1

# To incremenet value
a %+=% 2
print(a)
# [1] 3

# To decrement value
a %-=% 2
print(a)
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Nice to know about roperators and inplace (below) packages. 

Was hoping for a solution without the % wrapper. R 6.0 wish list :-)

Answer (score 0):

We could use inplace operators `%+<-%`  from `inplace`

```
library(inplace)
a <- 1
a %+<-% 2
```

-output

```
a
#[1] 3
```

Now, do the subtraction

```
a %-<-% 2
```

-output

```
a
#[1] 1
```

---

Or if we want to use the do this as it is, use the `reticulate` to call `python`

```
library(reticulate)
py_run_string("a = 1")
py_run_string("a += 2")
py$a
#[1] 3
```